# Best way to read and write data on google colab?

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, google-colaboratory, session-storage

I'm making an application that shows the correlation between your daily habits and your mood. Because python has so many of the components I need and I wan't this to be web based (also I'm not worried about the front end right now) I'm leaning towards using colab.

The problem is the session storage. I know how to work with pre-existing data but I'm totally unfamiliar with storing collected data with python. It's a light weight app and I'd like to use the panda's library to visualize the data.

The point is: I don't know how I should store the data that will be input on a daily basis on colab for future use. Of course, every time I run the colab, data collected will be cleared. What's the best way to store data from each use on colab? Can I create a csv file on my google drive and read / write to that file and if so what's the best method?

If colab seems like a bad option, I'll use javascript to collect the data & d3.js to visualize but I'd like to stick to colab if I can so I don't have to stand up my own webpage.

Comment: You can create a csv and read/write from it as detailed here: https://buomsoo-kim.github.io/colab/2020/05/09/Colab-mounting-google-drive.md/

If you want it to be web-based I would also look into Flask, as it is all in Python and you can spin up a small SQLite database for your information.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want it to be web-based, you can use [Heroku Student Plan](https://www.heroku.com/python) with [Github Education](https://education.github.com/) or  [PythonAnywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/). Because the colab session will stop after 12 hours and it is a headache to run it again.

In case, you still want to use Colab, one way is to save data into a file and keep it in Google Drive.  In this case,
Saving of data can be automated. But you'll need to get access token for Google Drive every session. Check [Example I/O notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=/v2/external/notebooks/io.ipynb)

Other methods are generally inconvenient